# NullInjectorError: No provider for class

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have injected class as dependency injection in component class and get an error

> NullInjectorError: No provider for class

Here is my code:

```
// Component
import { Formation } from './Models/Formation';

export class FormationComponent {
  constructor(private formation: Formation) { }
}

// Model Class
export class Formation {
}
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: If formation is a service add it to providers in your app module. If it is not a service then it should be, use Injectable annotation.

Comment: it's a simple class that represents the data model. How to annotate a class and why we can't define it like a simple class in C#. Can you show me please

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Angular 6+

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
    
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

#### Angular 5

**Method 1.** add class in `app.module.ts`'s providers

```
@NgModule({
  // ----
  providers: [
    MyService // added class in the providers
  ]
  // ----
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Method 2.**
add class in `component`'s  `provider`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    MyService // added class in the providers
  ]
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private service: MyService) {
  }

}
```

**Important:** Please don't forget to annotate the class as `@Injectable` so that you can inject it in the constructor i.e.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable() // class annotation as Injectable
export class MyService {

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Working in Ang 7::  
`@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and the solution is to add the service reference in the app module. once included then you can easily get rid out of it.

NOTE: Angular 4 are same solution. Checked